# Beware Little Red

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, music, acrostic

With my iPhone on shuffle this afternoon I’ve once again drawn inspiration from music. As always I wish you all the best of luck and I hope you enjoy the puzzle.

> *Guitar starts playing: Bm, Bm, G, F# (1,2,r,4,5,6,7,8)[4:4]{~160bpm)*
>
> Hahahaha this is about you...
>
> Beware, beware, be skeptical,
>
> A herring so true, it’s cryptical.
>
> It feels so natural,
>
> But a wolf in sheep’s clothing is more than a warning.
>
> ---
>
> Hey you, hey you, reading all these lines;
>
> Always, looking back, taking up your time.
>
> Used, no not broken, not just yet,
>
> Never giving up, ‘cause your mind is turning quick.
>
> To tell me...

- What song is this puzzle about?
- What song inspired the pattern used?

### ***WARNING***

These songs contain mature language so listen at your own risk. You’ve been warned. :)

Comment: Is "1,2,r,4" intentional?

Comment: @Stiv yes, the r states a rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What song inspired the pattern used? Likely

> "Wolf in Sheep's Clothing" (artist: Set it Off).

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJkj3DgW8Y0
Nightcore version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvl2e6X6PA4

**Lyrics** from the song that match: (source: lyricfind)

> Ha ha ha, this is about you 
> Beware, beware, be skeptical
> Of their smiles, their smiles of plated gold
> Deceit so natural
> But a wolf in sheep's clothing is more than a warning
>
> Bla-bla-black sheep, have you any soul?
> No sir, by the way, what the hell are morals
> Jack, be nimble, Jack, be quick
> Jill's a little whore and her alibis are dirty tricks
>
> So could you...

Answer (score 2):

The acrostic of the lyrics say

> HAUNT

So perhaps it's

> Haunted by Taylor Swift?

Rhythm seems alike, but I can't find mature language tho

Comment: Is there a passage that stands out in those lyrics? Hrmmm I wonder which one? I’m really just wanting to see it answered lol